# Ruby on Rails link_to wrong target?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a Project model(:link, :title, :content). 
My goal is to show users the whole link, and when they click on it, redirect to it. 
In my projects#show I have this code:

```
%h5= link_to @project.link, @project.link
```

However this redirects to this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/project_link_here
```

How could I get link do this:

```
project_link_here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link_to` url option relies on `url_for` (as explained in the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) docs). Read the [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) documentation to see what options you can pass in.

To get the full urls, you include `http://` in your `link`. This can be done by storing `Project#link`s with the "http://" protocol or taking it on later like this:

```
%h5= link_to @project.link, "http://#{@project.link}"
```

Alternatively, you could pass in the `:protocol` and `:host` options and set `only_path` to `false`, but you'd need to also store that information in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
%h5= link_to @project.link, project_link_path
```

in link_to helper, first argument is link name and the second argument is path or url. in your case  `@project.link` is a link name. replace `project_link_path` to your link path.